# Moving from http to https and I have thousands of 301s in place. How can I force all of them to https?

Tags: .htaccess, https, redirect

Over the past year, we've redesigned our site and implemented thousands of 301 redirects because we changed CMS and implemented a new URL structure.
For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /car-service-center/ http://www.example.com/services/
```

I have thousands of those examples.

Now, we've decided to move to https.

Obviously, to move to https, I'll need to force all traffic to https. I can do this using this command in the apache htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

So, how will my 301s be affected by this?
Do I need to update all of these because they refer to http:?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I think what will happen is you'll have two redirects, first to the http url, then from there to the https url. This should work but it's not optimal. Why not update your thousands of redirects to use https? Can you not just search-and-replace http -> https in the RedirectMatch rules?

Comment: Exactly what @MukundaModell said. What you're running will work... but it would be better to change your `301`'s to HTTPs

Comment: So, I simply need to update all of those to https, correct?

Comment: That should do it, indeed.